# SP ProcessBatchData inside the Event Receiver, slow performance issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, batch, multithreading

I am writing an Event Receiver on a Document Library to create a new list from the uploaded excel file. it runs on ItemAdded() and ItemUpdated() event.

Before calling a method to add new Items to List I need to clear old Items, I initially tried this with the traditional way (iterating in descending order and delete all records) and now with the [ProcessBatchData](http://merill.net/2008/02/efficiently-delete-purge-all-items-from-a-sharepoint-list/)

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                        {
                            if (site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName].Items.Count > 0)
                            {
                                var deleteBatch = site.OpenWeb().ProcessBatchData(BuildBatchDeleteCommand(site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName]));
                            }
                            InsertIntoList(ExcelRecords, site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName].Items);
                        }
```

ProcessBatachData is some what better but still not accurate the issue is that while debuggin once the control reaches the line `var deleteBatch = site.OpenWeb().ProcessBatchData(BuildBatchDeleteCommand(site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName]));`

It takes the control back to the document upload screen and most of the times doesn't hit the remaining code, However if records are really low ( < 100) then it process and takes the control to the next line ( `InsertIntoList(ExcelRecords, site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName].Items);` ).

Not able to figure out if its an thread issue, If I make this work my putting thread to sleep for sometime until the ProcessBatch finishes its job and control move to next line.

The complete function looks like

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            UpdateMarketingCalendar(properties);
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        }


private void UpdateMarketingCalendar(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                    {
                        SPList list = site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName];

                        bool recordsRetrieved;
                        DataTable ExcelRecords = GetRecordsFromExcel(properties.ListItem, out recordsRetrieved);

                        if (recordsRetrieved)
                        {
                            if (list.ItemCount > 0)
                            {
                                var deleteBatch = site.OpenWeb().ProcessBatchData(BuildBatchDeleteCommand(list));
                            }
                            InsertIntoList(ExcelRecords, list.Items);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

Geeks please point me to the right direction.
I really appreciate you help and time.

Vishal

Comment: Aside from Robert's advice I would also see if you can move this potentially-long-running code out of the SPListItem event receiver as it is primarily meant or short lived stuff. If you want to automatically generate the list from an excel, could perhaps use a workflow instead ? This will not get in the way of the user, and can also be made to run on a newly uploaded item's event.

Comment: Yepp, or use an SPLongTimeOperation: http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/39 for how to combine event receiver with Long Running Operation

Comment: You so still have two memory leaks in your code, opening webs without disposing them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the root cause of your performance issues, but part of it. Your code is written in a quite inefficient way, opening webs to the right and left and looking for the list multiple times. Something like this does the same thing but more efficiently:

If your feature is web scoped:

```
    var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
```

if site scoped

```
    var site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    if(site == null) return;
    var web = site.OpenWeb(properties.WebUrl);
```

and as MdMazzotti pointed out you would actually need to dispose the web in this scenario, I would use the using statement, replace the last line with this:

```
using(var web = site.OpenWeb(properties.WebUrl)){
```

and add an extra `}` at the end of the following
:

```
    if(web == null || !web.Exists) return;

    var list = web.Lists[listName]
    if (list != null && list.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        var deleteBatch = web.ProcessBatchData(BuildBatchDeleteCommand(list));
    }

    InsertIntoList(ExcelRecords, list.Items);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if declaring and further using Var's would make much difference to return time, would it ?

Comment: I think it will be even better to get SPSite and SPWeb objects directly from properties object since it is an event reciver. Something like      SPSite oSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb;

Comment: @VishalSachdeva, using vars by itself will not, but avoiding opening a lot of webs and iterating over all lists multiple times (yes that is what SP does when you call Lists["listName"]) will.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf, probably! Since he is not modifying the web directly I see no harm in that :), Will update my post

Comment: @Robert Lindgren thanks for valuable advice I'll quickly change my code and see if any luck, BTW any thing from top of your mind about putting thread to sleep before the request completes ?

Comment: Don't, you are in an event receiver and you want SharePoint to handle the threads. If you do not start a new thread yourself I see no gain in putting the thread to sleep at all

Comment: if you use OpenWeb, remember to always wrap it in a using statement (that automatically disposes of it).

Comment: @MdMazzotti Ah off course, great catch!

Comment: @RobertLindgren : Robert I have updated the method but no luck :( still the same behaviour, I have did some caching (updated the original question post), Kindly review it once. Thanks once again.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva, as I said I do not think this is your main problem, only part of the problem. Look at Cameron's comment on your question, he is suggesting that the code is so slow that the process is being killed by the IIS timeout.

Comment: @RobertLindgren : this statment "using(SPList list = site.OpenWeb().Lists[listName])" says that SPList is not IDisposeable.

Comment: Well the list is not, but the SPWeb is... The fact that you dispite my advice is using changing does not change the fact that you need to dispose webs opened with OpenWeb()